# How to remove "unknown class" from XIB file?

Tags: objective-c, warnings

When building an application, i get a warning:

> 2011-11-03 00:00:22.405 UnblockMe[26904:f803] Unknown class PuzzleView
>   in Interface Builder file.

This is a class, i had a while back but then removed. Evidently reference to it, still exists inside the XIB file.

How can i remove this reference and correct this error?

Comment: Have you looked inside the XIB xml directly to see if you can find that string in it?

Comment: I am not sure it is safe to edit XIB like that ... is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type “PuzzleView” into Interface Builder search field. It will switch to tree mode and show all views that are assigned this class. Change their class then to something else as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had that error in my application and no answer would correct it, so I will leave my problem and answser here, so anyone stepping on this thread might feel familiar and get lucky with it. (Running Xcode 3.2.6 on OSX10.6.8).

My problematic class was called **sera** and I had no idea how it was created. I've looked for any reference of it but in vain.
Then I searched with cmd+shift+f (global search) for sera. It revealed one entry, under MainMenu.xib. Double clicking the found sera class took me to the interface builder (where I had looked for it and nothing found).
So I tried the Interface Builder's Library search for sera. It actually found a class there, but I was sure I wasn't using it and had no idea how it was created.
Following an idea I got from SO of changing the .xib file from a text editor, I opened it with gedit and made a search for sera. I only got one result in the middle of all those lines of code. The line was `<string>sera</string>`
Since I don't know XML language I've just tried my luck deleting this line. When I tried opening the .xib in Interface Builder, I got the following error: [image]
Obviously not the solution, so I got back to the text editor and instead of deleting the whole line I just deleted `sera`, thus ending like `<string></string>`.
Saving and going back to Xcode, my .xib file opened correctly and compiling and running the project wouldn't pop that error on the console! :)